# Generic Method with Rest Template on List Return Type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a generic rest template method. The goal is to deserialize to a generic type, even if the type is parameterized. Unfortunately, when I try and deserialize, I get a list of hash maps or something similar. The type gets lost. Here's our code:

```
public List<UserValueDTO> getUserDetails() throws Exception {
    return getResponse("/user/details");
}

private <T> T getResponse(String endpoint) throws Exception {
    String token = authenticationService.getToken();
    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    headers.add("Authorization",  "Bearer " + token);
    HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
    try {
        ResponseEntity<T> response = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl + endpoint,
                HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<T> {});
        return response.getBody();
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
        throw new Exception("Unable to get a response from service");
    }
}
```

We also wrote an automated test that reveals the problem. Here's the test.

```
@Test
public void requestUserDetails_getsUserDetailsFromExternalService() throws Exception {
    doReturn("abcdefg-123456").when(mockAuthenticationService).getToken();

    server.expect(requestTo("http://localhost:8090/user/details"))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
            .andExpect(header("Authorization", "Bearer abcdefg-123456"))
            .andRespond(withSuccess("[\n" +
                    "  {\n" +
                    "    \"userId\": 12345,\n" +
                    "    \"value\": 500.0\n" +
                    "  },\n" +
                    "  {\n" +
                    "    \"userId\": 5555,\n" +
                    "    \"value\": 300.0\n" +
                    "  }\n" +
                    "]", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    List<UserValueDTO> userValueDTOs = accountServiceClient.getUserDetails();

    assertThat(userValueDTOs).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(
            new UserValueDTO.Builder().userId(12345).value(500.0).build(),
            new UserValueDTO.Builder().userId(5555).value(300.0).build()
    );
}
```

And the result of this test when run against this code is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
   <[{"userId"=12345, "value"=500.0}, {"userId"=5555, "value"=300.0}]>
to contain exactly in any order:
   <[com.project.dto.UserValueDTO@408516e7,
     com.project.dto.UserValueDTO@407560ad]>
elements not found:
  <[com.project.dto.UserValueDTO@408516e7,
    com.project.dto.UserValueDTO@407560ad]>
and elements not expected:
  <[{"userId"=12345, "value"=500.0}, {"userId"=5555, "value"=300.0}]>
```

Is there a way to not lose the parameterized type on the list when deserializing? Thanks!

Comment: I can't help very well because I don't know Spring, but `new ParameterizedTypeReference<T> {}` looks very suspicious to me, knowing how classes like that work. That won't create a `ParameterizedTypeReference<List<UserValueDTO>>`. It will create a `ParameterizedTypeReference<T>`, whose type argument is the instance of `java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable` declared by the method `getResponse`. Try `System.out.println(new ParameterizedTypeReference<T> {}.getType());` to see what I mean.

Comment: @Radiodef Yikes. It says the Type is "T". That's no good. Is there any other way to get a parameterized type here for a generic?

Comment: You would have to pass it in to the method as an argument, unfortunately. You have to instantiate the `ParameterizedTypeReference` with the actual type argument you want, like `new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<UserValueDTO>>() {}`.

Comment: @Radiodef It's not the prettiest thing in the world, but it's what we're looking for! Thanks!

Comment: One question, shouldn't your generic method have a signature like private <T>List<T> getResponse(String endpoint)  and consequently using List<T> instead of <T> also for ResponseEntity and ParameterizedTypeReference?

Answer (score 1):

Based on our exchange in the comments, the issue is the use of `new ParameterizedTypeReference<T>() {}`. The reason this doesn't work has to do with how these type token/type reference/etc. objects work. (This was originally described in Neal Gafter's blog post [here](https://gafter.blogspot.nl/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html).)

```
abstract class TypeRefExample<T> {
    final Type typeOfT;

    TypeRefExample() {
        // Get the extending subclass.
        // (Usually an anonymous class like TypeRefExample<String>() {}.)
        Class<?> subclass = getClass();
        // Get the generic superclass, which is the type
        // in the extends clause.
        // This can be explicit like:
        //  class FooTypeRef extends TypeRefExample<Foo> {}
        // or implicit as in the case of an anonymous class:
        //  new TypeRefExample<Foo>() {}
        // which declares a class something like:
        //  class OuterClass$1 extends TypeRefExample<Foo> {}
        Type superclass = subclass.getGenericSuperclass();
        // Then if the superclass is a ParameterizedType
        // its type argument can be retrieved.
        typeOfT = ((ParameterizedType) superclass)
                    .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        // A real implementation should do some more
        // work but that's the basic idea.
    }
}
```

So if you have a `new ParameterizedTypeReference<T>() {}` then `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` returns the type in the implicit extends clause, which is `ParameterizedTypeReference<T>` and whose type argument is the type variable `T`.

If the use of this `ParameterizedTypeReference` is critical to getting the test to work, then you have to pass it in as an argument, unfortunately. It has to be created with an actual type argument `new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<UserValueDTO>>() {}`.

Guava [`TypeToken`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#TypeToken-java.lang.Class-) has some bells and whistles for resolving type variables which are declared on a class, but doing the same for type variables declared on a method is actually impossible because there's no way to reify the type argument to a method at the call site.